# type-casting abstract class type to struct type with a integer member

Tags: c++

I am studing Blender's GHOST code and found the following statement in GHOST_CreateSystem C-API function

```
  GHOST_ISystem::createSystem();
  GHOST_ISystem *system = GHOST_ISystem::getSystem();

  return (GHOST_SystemHandle)system;
```

GHOST_ISystem is an abstract class for a specific operating system such as win32, linux.

GHOST_SystemHandle is defined as structure type as follows:

```
typedef struct GHOST_SystemHandle__ {
      int unused; 
    } * GHOST_SystemHandle
```

I am not familiar with this kind of practice type-casting a pointer to class into a pointer to struct type with an integer member.

It would be appreciated to enlighten me the background about it.

Comment: `GHOST_SystemHandle__` is a reserved identifier since it contains a double underscore. It should not be declared in C++ code (although it is fine in C). The cast is only safe if `alignof(GHOST_ISystem)` is an integer multiple of `alignof(GHOST_SystemHandle__)`.

Comment: @user17732522 you mean  portable. whether that matters or not, is platform-defined (sometimes OS and memory model, sometimes hardware).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `reinterpret_cast` is not required to preserve a misaligned address (the result of the cast is _unspecified_), although granted I don't think that matters on actual implementations.

Comment: @user17732522 here are only pointers to unrelated types are being casts. SO we are talking about both alignof of pointers and of pointee, and of pointer size. some systems may consider different pointer formats, albeit now its very rare compared to 30 years ago.

Comment: Tbh, it seems that code was originally written in C, then it survived "dummy refactoring", where global functions where changed into static members and compilation units into classes. In C++ this could be solved more elegantly, by using a class with common beginning sequence to make it safe(r).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Even if the pointer types have different representations round-trip explicit casts (through object pointer types) ought to preserve the pointer value, given the alignment requirement I mentioned is fulfilled, if the implementation is supposed to conform to the standards, as far as I can tell. (Not saying there aren't "C" implementations that don't conform to the standard.)

Comment: @user17732522 well, there are entire mass-produced CPU architectures which would be more strict than standard, albeit alignof equivalence for  the underlying "int" field for `unused` for them would be enough. Those tricks often go unnoticed because common desktop CPU, the x86-64 arch is more lax than standard requires, and next one, ARM, is conforming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract class CANNOT be instantiated, to wit it cannot be converted. What happens here is a conversion of pointer values.

The calls `GHOST_ISystem::createSystem();` and `GHOST_ISystem::getSystem();` are calls to static functions. The latter returns a pointer to `GHOST_ISystem`. Pointer is a separate compound type and pointer to any declared type may materialized. A pointer to an abstract class-type can hold value of pointer to any derived type. `GHOST_ISystem*` is its static type while its dynamic type can vary.

The C-style cast syntax `(GHOST_SystemHandle)system;` is considered *faux pas* in C++ as it is too permitting, unsafe conversion. In this particular case it is treated as `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer `GHOST_SystemHandle__ *`.

The content of pointer `system` is bytewise copied to an instance of `GHOST_SystemHandle`, which is also a pointer. This would be hinged on assumption that all pointers in implementation have similar content and same size and that access by dereferencing the result would be legal.

Likely, the underlying reason was that derived types would have an integer field or an subobject with same alignment. Strictly speaking, result is *unspecified*. Memory model of original class and `GHOST_SystemHandle__` should match. This assumes too many things:

1. The abstract base class-type have no non-static member variable or it contains an equivalent member variable.
2. The implementation is conforming to late-enough standard to ensure that
   base type subobject got zero size, if it doesn't have non-static member variables.
3. The alignment requirement of
   derived type in question is same as alignment requirement of
   `GHOST_SystemHandle__`. It it's not, result of `*system->unused` is
   undefined.

There is a number of ways it could be avoided in C++ and none was used, which suggests that code was converted from C without much of refactoring done while keeping interface type formats same for compatibility.